# Error while configuring LDAP over SSL : TLS certificate verification: Error

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap

I am configuring OPENLDAP for SSL/TLS. I need to configure ldap for secure connection on port like 636.
I have already prepared configurations like LDAPTLS_CACERT="/etc/openldap/cacerts/ca.cert.pem". However while connecting with the server, I am facing below **"TLS certificate verification: Error"**.
I am using below ldapsearch command to check the connection :

*env LDAPTLS_CACERT="/etc/openldap/cacerts/ca.cert.pem" ldapsearch -H ldaps://192.168.1.XXX:636 -ZZ -d 1 -b "ou=MyTeam,ou=People,dc=geekforgeek,dc=local" -D "cn=ldapLoger,ou=LdapLoger,dc=geekforgeek,dc=local" -s base "(&(emailAddress=%v)(objectclass=ePerson))"*

Following error i am getting as a result :

````
TLS trace: SSL3 alert write:fatal:unknown CA
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in error
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in error
TLS: can't connect: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain).
ldap_err2string
ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
        additional info: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain)```

Any input on why this error occurs! Please suggest.
````